# WordPress theme resource won't load over VPN

Tags: theme-development, javascript, css

We are having WordPress portal over Intranet (LAN) that we use for internal purposes. **We have set xyz.org host for Intranet**. Over the LAN it is working fine.

The issue is when our CEO access it over VPN the site resources such as CSS, JS won't load.

I am aware that WordPress will use one domain set in options table to point all resources. Since we have xyz.org set for Intranet it will go to look resource for the same over VPN. However, VPN has different IP so WordPress is not able to find them.

Is there any fix or workaround for this issue?

Is it possible to set the same host xyz.org over VPN or my CEO's computer and will that work? Any idea or solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

1st variant. CEO should add xyz.org with proper IP to the `hosts` file on his computer.

This will work on the local machine. However, if it is a laptop, and sometimes the same laptop will be used in intranet, you need another solution.

2nd variant. In `hosts` file, point abc.org to outer IP. On site, install plugin Multiple Domains and setup it to work with abc.org, too. Now your site is able to respond to xyz.org and abc.org. At home via VPN, CEO will be able to see site at abc.org address, and at work, over intranet, he will be able to see the site at xyz.org address.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will follow this and get back to you with the outcome. Thanks once again...!